# How do I implement search on each table in php

Tags: jquery, ajax

For instance I have two tables

```
<div id="fortablea">
<input type="text">
<table id="tablea">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="fortableb">
<input type="text">
<table id="tableb">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Both have their own input text bars in their respective divs.

I want to stay on the same page and if I type anything in input of table a then only its contents should change remaining all other tables unaffected.

contents of each tables are coming from two functions

```
function tableA($name);
function tableB($name2);
```

Is there any possible way to accomplish this through jQuery?

Comment: Can anybody explain this question? Oh, you should not have two `id="tablea"`, id's should be unique.

Comment: Yes there are many possible way to accomplish this through jQuery with unique table id, please try first at your end.

Comment: Apology for typo mistake.

Comment: Unsure what the actual question is. If you want to know which table contains the input that was changed, you can do `$(this).closest('table').attr('id')`

Comment: For instance I have data on both tables. Now if I input something in textbar of table a then table a contents should refresh and renew without affecting table b

Comment: In your title, you ask to do it in php. But in question, you ask for jQuery. Please fix the title and the tags (no need `php` tag here if it's jQuery)

Comment: Look at the functions!

Answer (score 0):

You could do some name convention and add some css class. E.g. with html:

```
<div id="fortablea" class="autoSearch">
<input type="text">
<table id="tablea">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="fortableb" class="autoSearch">
<input type="text">
<table id="tableb">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and jQuery

```
var tableSearchers = {
  fortablea: function(keyword){...}, //equals id of table (name convention)
  fortableb: function(keyword){...}//equals id of table (name convention)
}
```

and in some `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.autoSearch input', function(){
   tableSearchers[$(this).parents('.autoSearch:first').attr('id')]($(this).text());
});
```

*This of course can be extended to multiple tables of same structure. Also in practical application you might want to insert some delay before triggering the function (and wait for more input)*

Even though I'm sure there is a more clean solution than that.